# button as a cancel redirects to previous page

Tags: jquery, html, spring, jsp, browser

Is there a function I can attach as a click event of a button to make the browser go back to previous page without using history.go() function and window.location.href?

```
      <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" onclick="history.go(-1)"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Simon, it is always better to let the user know what is the target of a link.
In this solution you will print a link:

```
<script>
  document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back</a>');
</script>
```

But if you really want to use an input button, then you can use the Nikhila proposition:

```
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" onclick="goPrev()"/>
<script>
  function goPrev()
  {
    window.history.back();
  }
</script>
```

**NOTE** This is only JS code, the link or the button will appear where the script bloc will be added. If you want, you can add use JQuery to specify where you can will add the new content, or use appendChild (see the code in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Have a nice day

Comment: Hello, can you close this ticket if the responses answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

This solution has the benefit of showing the URL of the linked-to page on hover, as most browsers do by default, instead of history.go(-1) or similar:

```
1 <script>
2    document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back</a>');
3 </script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" onclick="goPrev()"/>

<script>
function goPrev()
{
window.history.back();
}
</script>
```